My Android app is unable to import a com.google.mlkit library but can import others
I'm trying to implement Gemini AI in my app and I'm stuck at this point: I'm able to import com.google.mlkit.nl.smartreply.SmartReplySuggestion and
com.google.mlkit.nl.smartreply.TextMessage but not com.google.mlkit.nl.smartreply.SmartReplyClient
Here's my app-level gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdk 34
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.uomini.myaiassistantben"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += ['META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', 'META-INF/LICENSE', 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt', 'META-INF/license.txt', 'META-INF/NOTICE', 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt', 'META-INF/notice.txt', 'META-INF/ASL2.0', 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
}
namespace 'com.uomini.myaiassistantben'
}

dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:7.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0"
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0' // If you are using Gson as your JSON converter
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-speech:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit:17.0.0'
implementation libs.common// Assuming this is the Gemini SDK

def lifecycle_version = "2.8.3"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

// Google Calendar API
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.33.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev20220715-1.32.1'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:smart-reply:17.0.3'

// Gemini AI SDK (Note: This is a placeholder, as the actual SDK might not be publicly available yet)
// implementation 'com.google.ai.gemini:gemini-sdk:1.0.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:24.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-to-speech:18.0.0'

// CameraX for camera interaction
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.4'

/**
// Cloud vision libraries
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:3.43.0'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:2.46.0'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:2.6.1'

// Required for one-shot operations (to use `ListenableFuture` from Guava Android)
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-android'

// Required for streaming operations (to use `Publisher` from Reactive Streams)
implementation 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0'**/
}

My project-level gradle file is as follows:

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2'
    //        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'  // Performance Monitoring plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/'
    }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Since there is nothing by that class name in the documentation, are you sure that it is supposed to exist?

@CommonsWare There's com.google.mlkit.nl.smartreply, but When I try to import and library beginning with com.google.mlkit, I get a not found error.

@CommonsWare I'm not sure my email got to you. My question in it was whether you're available for consultation.

There is no class as com.google.mlkit.nl.smartreply.SmartReplyClient in ML Kit library
